# Confused about this behavior in my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use this function to return as a global variable a `String` object that is the contents of a local text file. Right now it is returning an empty `String`.

```
function get_words()
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", "wordsEn.txt", true);
    var allText = new String(); 
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
            }
        }

    }
    rawFile.send(null);
    return allText;
}
```

However, when I change the body of the second if statement to

```
allText = rawFile.responseText;
alert(allText);
```

I do get an `alert` message that is the correct contents of the text file.

***However***, when I instead put the `alert` message right before the `return` statement, I get an empty `alert` message.

I would be happy if you could give me some insight on the behavior here and possibly help me fix it to accomplish the task of returning as a string the contents of the text file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because the ajax call takes some time to complete, it's running asynchronous. Within the 2nd `if`, you're within the `onreadystatechange` function, which is called multiple times for various statuses. One of them (`200`) will carry your data and alert it properly.

Comment: this one too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Please people, vote to close instead of rushing to give a bad one or three lines answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing asyncrhonously.

Basically this means that the anonymous function attached to `onreadystatechange` will only execute upon receipt of the data. So, when your `alert` is inside of this function (below the `allText = rawFile.responseText`) the variable `allText` will contain your file contents (as it's had a chance to be populated).

If, however, you put the alert above the return statement the `allText` variable is not yet populated and the function returns before the file contents are received.

One way you could overcome this, is by passing a callback function to `get_words`.